# Implicit instantiation depending on scoped or unscoped enumeration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

14.7.3/6 says the following:

> > If a template, a member template or the member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that
> >     specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. If the program does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit specialization that is declared but not defined.

It then gives the following example:

```
template<class T> struct A
{
    enum E : T;
    enum class S : T;
};

template<> enum A<int>::E : int { eint };       // OK

template<> enum class A<int>::S : int { sint }; // OK

template<class T> enum A<T>::E : T { eT };

template<class T> enum class A<T>::S : T { cT };

template<> enum A<char>::E : char { echar }; // ill-formed, A<char>::E was instantiated
                                             // when A<char> was instantiated

template<> enum class A<char>::S : char { schar }; // OK
```

I'm not following how it is able to compile the last line but not the one before it. I expected both examples to fail because both `A<char>::E` and `A<char>::S` were being implicitly instantiated. I notice when I remove `class` from the enum-key of `S` in the primary template the last line fails with the same message as the other. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit instantiation of a class template implicitly instantiates the definitions of unscoped member enumerations, but only the declarations of scoped member enumerations.

§14.7.1 [temp.inst]/p1 (emphasis added):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of **the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions**, default arguments, or exception-specifications of the
>   class member functions, member classes, **scoped member
>   enumerations**, static data members and member templates; and it
>   causes the implicit instantiation of **the definitions** of **unscoped
>   member enumerations** and member anonymous unions.

Comment: @T.C. And where is there A<char> instantiated in the code snippet?